# NTFS Corrupted. Input/Output Error

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I recently had a problem where one of my NTFS hard drives stopped working.

I have tried chkdsk /f on windows 10, 3 times with no success.
And also sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdi1, with no success.

Is there anyone who knows any other approach other than re-formatting?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 1):

If you need know if the phisical disk is correct you should see the smart info of the provider....

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda # Show the phisical state of disk sda from smart...
```

If you have reaollcated sectors or  Offline_Uncorrectable you should save all 
the data inside that disk and change it...

If not the problem is in the Filesystem...

Check the filesystem with the tools of the provider... if is ntfs you should see the info of chdsk...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing TestDisk

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

and running a scan on your drive

```
sudo testdisk
```

Be aware that the scan might take long time depending on the size of the disk.

If it doesn't work, you have no other option but to use a tool like 'Hdd Regenerator' or 'Spinrite' from a bootable cd.

Answer (score 0):

If running chkdsk isn't working you might have a bad hard drive. I would suggest using a utility like [GSmartControl](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gsmartcontrol/) to test the physical to make sure it's not already dead or about to be.